# libssh2 and C++

Tags: c++, libssh

When I try to use libssh2 in my C++ class, I keep getting the following errors:

```
undefined reference to `libssh2_session_init_ex'
undefined reference to `libssh2_session_startup'
```

If I do the same thing using C, everything works fine.

Any help?

Following is the build command

```
g++ -Wall -g -I/libssh2-1.2.4/src -I/libssh2-1.2.4/include -L/libssh2-1.2.4/src/obj -L/openssl-0.9.8k/ -L/SecuritySDK/3.0.13/RC/LATEST/security/lib  -lssh2 -ldl -lnsl -lresolv -lhash -lhandlers -lcrypto -lssl -lz -lbpwp3   rhost.o rpipe.o rutils.o -o rpipe
```

following is the class member function

```
void rhost::InitSession()
{
    m_session = libssh2_session_init();
    if ( libssh2_session_startup(m_session, m_sock) )
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Failure establishing SSH session\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    return;
}
```

Yes platform is linux

Comment: Sounds to me like your not linking against the right libraries.

Comment: Show us some of your C++ code (especially the part that calls the functions that fail to link).  Also, are you using Linux?  Which distro/version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your call to `g++ -Wall -g -I/libssh2-1.2.4/src -I/libssh2-1.2.4/include -L/libssh2-1.2.4/src/obj -L/openssl-0.9.8k/ -L/SecuritySDK/3.0.13/RC/LATEST/security/lib  rhost.o rpipe.o rutils.o -o rpip -lssh2 -ldl -lnsl -lresolv -lhash -lhandlers -lcrypto -lssl -lz -lbpwp3`.

The order of libraries and object files in the parameter list matters. Read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608780/compiling-a-swig-python-wrapper-for-a-static-library/4609011#4609011).

Answer (score 1):

If C works and C++ doesn't, then it sounds like you're failing to include the libssh2 function prototypes in an `extern "C" {}` block, as described [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html#faq-32.3).  (You should double-check the header file; I'm a bit surprised that it doesn't use `extern "C" {}` itself.)

Comment: @Avinash:  Then I suspect that you're doing something wrong in your build.  You'll need to provide more information about how you're building your code.

Comment: When I say C work, I tried the examples provided with libssh which are in C and they work with the same build command.

Comment: @Avinash: Would you mind posting the exact build command that the example code uses?  I wonder if you're somehow getting a different libssh2 (one provided by your Linux distro?) that doesn't define those functions...

Comment: I am not using libssh2 provided by linux distro. I am have build my own libssh2

Comment: @Avinash: Are you building libssh2 itself with the C or C++ compiler?